# external function timeout and retry behavior

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

viewing Azure function logs, an external function appears to retry a query after ~30 seconds if no response is received. queries that complete in less than 30 seconds are successfully returned to snowflake.

Azure function is setup with a consumption plan and default timeout is 5 minutes.

any plans, thoughts, opinions about changing this behavior, for example:

- configurable
- back off to allow additional time (maybe also configurable).

appreciate

- documented [guidance](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/external-functions-general.html) - including send less, function and snowflake in same region - check
- preview feature
- change may already be afoot
- balance between performance and getting the data

shout out to the function doco. folks, nice work.

cheers,

Comment: Azure functions are allowed to be configured to timeout after 5 minutes, instead of 30 seconds.  Is it possible to modify the Azure Function itself to run longer for you?

Comment: @MikeWalton added that missing detail to the question: functions run successfully for periods longer than 30 seconds. functions that complete in < 30 seconds are  successfully returned to snowflake.